# How can I detect consecutive hours in a MySQL DATETIME column?

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a table like this:

```
DESCRIBE time_slots;

  id          int(11)
  user_id     int(11)
  start_time  datetime
```

The `start_time` field is always an hour increment (e.g. `2013-09-04 16:00:00`)

Our data scientist wants to query this table in a way that identifies consecutive `start_time` records per `user_id` such that she can create a derived table that looks like this:

```
  id          int(11)
  user_id     int(11)
  start_time  datetime
  end_time    datetime
```

For example, given this data:

```
user_id: 5, start_time: 2013-09-04 16:00:00
user_id: 5, start_time: 2013-09-04 17:00:00
user_id: 5, start_time: 2013-09-04 18:00:00

user_id: 6, start_time: 2013-09-04 16:00:00
user_id: 6, start_time: 2013-09-04 17:00:00
user_id: 6, start_time: 2013-09-04 18:00:00

user_id: 6, start_time: 2013-09-04 20:00:00
user_id: 6, start_time: 2013-09-04 21:00:00
user_id: 6, start_time: 2013-09-04 22:00:00
```

... we could derive this output:

```
user_id: 5, start_time: 2013-09-04 16:00:00, end_time: 2013-09-04 18:00:00
user_id: 6, start_time: 2013-09-04 16:00:00, end_time: 2013-09-04 18:00:00
user_id: 6, start_time: 2013-09-04 20:00:00, end_time: 2013-09-04 22:00:00
```

There may be multiples of these start/end "blocks" for a given user per day (but they won't overlap).

Any ideas how this can be done in SQL before I go to Plan B (set up a denormalized data warehouse)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your database...  windowing functions can achieve this.   Generate a column that represents the delta with previous column (so you need it ordered by user_id, startTime);  You can then use that delta column to do grouping into the groups.  Since continuous blocks would be represented by "1" in the delta, and a new block would have a higher number.

You can maybe achieve this also by doing a join with a subselect and have it offset by 1, such as joining on ROW_NUMBER and ROW_NUMBER-1  and then you can calculate the delta between timestamps, and work some magic with the outerselect to get what you want.  The key is the delta.

You can do something like this:

```
SET @prevUser := null;
SET @prevStartTime := 0;
SET @groupNumber := 1;
SET @groupPrevUser := null;


select 
    user,
    groupNumber,
    min(startTime),
    max(endTime),
    max(endTime) - min(startTime) as 'duration'
from
    (SELECT 
        user,
            startTime,
            endTime,
            delta,
            IF(delta != 10000 || @groupPrevUser <> user, @groupNumber:=@groupNumber + 1, @groupNumber) 'groupNumber',
            @groupPrevUser:=user
    from
        (SELECT 
        user,
            startTime,
            endTime,
            IF(@prevUser <> user || @prevStartTime = 0, endTime - startTime, startTime - @prevStartTime) AS delta,
            @prevUser:=user,
            @prevStartTime:=startTime
    FROM
        queries
    ORDER BY user , startTime) userData) userGroupData
group by user , groupNumber
```

Get this result:

```
# user, groupNumber, min(startTime), max(endTime), duration
bob, 1, 1392060000, 1392080000, 20000
bob, 2, 1392090000, 1392100000, 10000
jim, 3, 1392150000, 1392180000, 30000
```

Using this base table:

```
# user, startTime, endTime
bob, 1392060000, 1392070000
bob, 1392070000, 1392080000
bob, 1392090000, 1392100000
jim, 1392150000, 1392160000
jim, 1392160000, 1392170000
jim, 1392170000, 1392180000
```

Comment: Windowing functions do not exist in MySQL.

Comment: Doing a self join using RANK and RANK-1 or the user_id, starttime - 1 hour  as keys would give you the same ability

Comment: btw, InfiniDB which is a MySQL compliant database (open source GPLv2) has windowing functions built ontop of standard MySQL functions.

Comment: Looks as if MySQL can be fooled into a RANK. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26e10/9 Then you could use a self-join instead of the semi-join I suggest. Don't know if the procedural language handling takes away the speed improvement I would expect from a self join. Don't want to start a DB war, but this is a real lack in MySQL.

Comment: Same way as calculating a rank in MySQL, you can calculate the delta

Comment: Added the SQL to achieve result

Comment: She ended up achieving this using some combination of suggestions from this answer and its comments (e.g. RANK), so I suppose this is the answer to award. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion is that you change the schema to add a counter for block_by_id. Then your problem is a simple min-max. And when a record is created, the block number can be determined with a trigger by seeing if (1) there is already a record for this user_id and (2) is it more than an hour earlier than the new record. I suppose you could see this as denormalized, in which case, the idea is to figure out blocks "on the fly".

```
SELECT user_id, MIN(start_time) AS start_time, MAX(start_time) AS start_time
FROM time_slots t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1 FROM time_slots AS t2 WHERE t1.user_id = t2.user_id
       AND timestampdiff(HOUR, t1.start_time, t2.start_time)=1
/* replace with date arithmetic function of your RDBMS if need be */ 
    )
GROUP BY user_id;
```

I don't have any experience tuning MySQL. It may be that different timediff expressions will allow it to use an index on `(user_id, start_time)`.